# Spring MVC map json or encoded parameters to @RequestParam

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring controller with this method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/testUrl", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
    consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})
public @ResponseBody String method(@RequestParam String propertyId, @RequestParam String comments) {...}
```

I want this to be able to handle request bodies of

```
"propertyId=123&comments=something"
```

AND the json equivalent:

```
{"propertyId":"123","comments":"comment"}
```

Right now only, the form-url-encoded (first request body) works. What is the best way to do get both of these to work?

Comment: Technically, they *aren't* request parameters. Use an `@ModelAttribute`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@RequestParam` to handle **url parameters** like the first ones you are doing. Use `@RequestBody` to handle the **body**  of the request and then set the value to be resolved into a wrapper class like

```
public @ResponseBody String handleMyDTO(@RequestParam String propertyId, @RequestParam String comment, @RequestBody MyDTO dto){//impl goes here}
```

Where the MyDTO is

```
public class MyDTO {
     //use @JsonPropery("my_custom_prop_name") if you want to use a     //different name to map the field into json
     private String propertyId;
     private String comment;
     //getters setters default constructor
}
```

**NOTE** `@RequestBody` is eligible for validation using the `@Valid` annotation together

If you are sending form content to the controller you might want to do it with `@ModelAttribute MyDTO dto` instead of `@RequestParam` fields